# Authentication with easyXDM

Tags: easyxdm

I am successfully using easyxdm (with the iframe-intermediate.html methodology) to pull content from a remote server to resize in an iframe on a website, we would now like to lock down our remote content with a username/password, is it possible to re-architect our current implementation to pass a authentication header to allow us to continue to pull the content? we are currently using the below

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var transport = new easyXDM.Socket({
        remote: url,
        container: "iframeContainer",
        onMessage: function (message, origin) {
            message = (Number(message) + 50);
            this.container.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].style.height = message + "px";
        }
    });  
});
```